# How to match all only number tokens in a string?

Tags: python, regex

I have an example string like this:

`1 23 456 123asd asd123 12 3456789`

I want to create a regex to match all **only number tokens**, so that it would match with `1`, `23`, `456`, `12`, and `3456789`.

I already tried to create the regex which is `\b[^a-zA-Z\s]\d*[^a-zA-Z\s]`, but somehow it only matches with `23`. It won't match with `1`, and all the other number tokens after `23`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you expecting this to match *all* number tokens?  With a single run of digits?

Comment: I did. I thought that by using regex pattern I could match with multiple values. Turns out that what I need is a function such as `findall` from `re` module, as said by @Joshua Fox in the answers section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The  simple regex `\d+` will do this.  And you want an API that returns multiple values, for example `findall`.

```
import re
found = re.findall(r'\d+', '1 23 456 123asd asd123 12 3456789')
print(found)
```

outputs

```
['1', '23', '456', '123', '123', '12', '3456789']
```

Comment: Oh wow thank you very much for your answer. I've been looking everywhere for such regex pattern but can't find it. I really thought I can use a single regex to match all the numbers. I didn't know that I just need to use a single function.
Thanks Joshua 

Answer (score 0):

`\b\d+\b`
gets only numbers and no letters concatenated

Answer (score 0):

The `\b` assert already match word boundary, so there no need to rematch with `[^a-zA-Z\s]`. Besides, this match list doesn't include start or end of match, so "1" and "3456789" are not matched.

`\b[0-9]+\b` will be enough to match only numeric tokens : it match groups of digits not inside another bloc (thanks to word boundary assets)

Answer (score 0):

Another simple solution is `[^\D]+`

```
import re
found = re.findall('[^\D]+',"this is test #23 1 23 456 123asd asd123 12 3456789")
print(found)

['23', '1', '23', '456', '123', '123', '12', '3456789']
```

Comment: How would this pattern work with `"this is test #23"` ?

Comment: I'd just supposed the sample string, now I updated my solution with `\D`

Comment: This is not correct. Within brackets `[]`, the caret `^` becomes NOT.  The OP wants digits.

Comment: This is completely correct, as it means not non-digit which means digits :D